# Why the url of user avatar image file for most of websites is so complex?

Tags: php, database-design, profile, avatar

I found that most of url of user avatar image file is so long and combined a lot of data.

For example, the facebook:

```
https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash4/371533_1567227XXX_1135411XXX_q.jpg
```

We knew the `1135411XXX` is user id and `q` is file size, but what `371533` and `1567227XXX` stand for?

Others:

Linkedin `http://m3.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_60_60/p/4/000/165/0e4/3b2dcXX.jpg`

Tumblr `http://24.media.tumblr.com/avatar_4de452cedeXX_64.png`

We can just name the file name by user id and it looks much shorter and easier like this:

`<img src="http://domain.com/images/avatar/' . $user_id . '.jpg"/>`

But why they make the url so long and complex? What kind of potential problem I didn`t considered?

Comment: If it was so then you could easily write a script and extract all the user avatars from their site. I think that might be a security matter..

Comment: Caching and performance are also a big deal for sites this big, for such commonly served images.

Comment: @Ivo If just use the user id, it`s also possible for caching.

Answer (score 1):

They are complex systems, and probably have many uses for an avatar picture. Maybe in different places they need different sizes. Maybe they need a url which is accessible only from their site.

Maybe they need a uniquely generated url so that the file can be served statically from a server, decreasing load.

Twitter's url seems quite simple, really. There's the cdn domain, then `avatar_` and a unique id, and then image size (i.e `_64`).

Linkedin's seems to have resizing parameters in the url, to enable different sizes, followed by some other parameters I wouldn't know, and then again followed by a unique id.

Facebook has three uniqueids to generate the filename, I think they do this again so that they can serve static files fast. I'd guess one of them would be the album id, one is the profile id, and the last might be the picture id.

Comment: Twitter is `user id / upload file name`

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple reasons:

1. Anti-Miner
2. Security trough obscurity
3. Generated UID
4. Extra Information like size and pixels

Imagine what whould happen if i know that you use 5 character ID's, i would start to load every possible id on your server and completely mine off all the pictures from your users.

You would have lots of traffic.
Your users would sue you for not protecting their privacy.

It is good to have for example a hash algorythm for such a path for user "userone" the hash would be '1236662231' and use that as the path, so that others have difficulties to understand the actual path and will not mining your website for info & pictures.

Answer (score 0):

When a photo is saved, there is usually generated a GUID for it.

GUIDs consist of numbers, letter and symbols. They are usually long enough, so that sufficient quantity of images can be stored. They are also unique, so image size and user id aren't enough.

GUIDs are often generated based on the upload time. Together with user id this guarantees uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

- The urls may have picture id or album id or user id or may be time
  stamp(in int so that images doesn't cached with same names)
- The    domain is complex because of the Content Delivery Network for 
  Facebook it is akamaihd and so may have different for others...